# css z-index positionning does not work on my prestashop

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, z-index

I do have a custom template but in the checkout page all is positionning in column (boostrap)
for the login, the left fieldset is expanding to the right.

I tried to apply a z-index on it to make it over the right column, but it does not work.

the content of the right column is still over the left.

Below is image of my website

[image]

and here is elements as shown on chrome, as you can see I applied a z-index which is not taken in count.

[image]

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: For `z-index` to work, the element must have `position: relative/absolute/fixed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to position your element before giving it a `z-index` value

```
<fieldset style="position:relative; z-index:999;">
```

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski Yes you can use any position you like